# Pdf support in php 5.2.17 version

Tags: php

My php version is 5.2.17. I want to create a pdf using php. i have written this code

```
$mypdf = PDF_new();
        PDF_open_file($mypdf, "");
        PDF_begin_page($mypdf, 595, 842);
        $myfont = PDF_findfont($mypdf, "Times-Roman", "host", 0);
        PDF_setfont($mypdf, $myfont, 10);
        PDF_show_xy($mypdf, "Sample PDF, constructed by PHP in real-time.", 50, 750);
        PDF_show_xy($mypdf, "Made with the PDF libraries for PHP.", 50, 730);
        PDF_end_page($mypdf);
        PDF_close($mypdf);

        $mybuf = PDF_get_buffer($mypdf);
        $mylen = strlen($mybuf);
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Length: $mylen");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=gen01.pdf");
        print $mybuf;

        PDF_delete($mypdf)
```

;

this code is working perfectly on my localhost but on my server this is not working . On my server `$mypdf` is not created. on my server php 5.2.17 version is used. what is the problem ? i thinks pdf library is not working on my srever. Please help me

Comment: I don't think the extension is bundled with PHP, are you sure it's installed on the server?

Comment: error reporting and display error E_ALL and on?

Comment: i think this extension is already bundeled in php version 5.2.17. Well may be it is not there. How can i check this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server has PDFlib installed.

Comment: Try calling `phpinfo` and see if it is listed under Extensions, or check your php.ini.